# MacBook Pro Screen Flickering when using HDMI to VGA adapter to connect to external monitor

Tags: mac, display, hdmi, vga-adapter, vga

My MacBook Pro 2014 keeps flickering when I plug in a HDMI to VGA converter to it. I am using HDMI to plug in the HDMI to VGA converter (which is plugged in to my monitor). The screen is just black and then the Mac starts flashing. The external monitor does not have any effect. I tried out the wiring and monitor on another windows computer and it worked smoothly.

Comment: Since MacBook Pro doesn't have any VGA ports, I believe you are using HDMI to VGA converter, not the way around. If so, please update your question title to reflect this.

Comment: Did U ever solve this? I have the same issue - multiple monitors for me tho with hdmi-vga converter. The monitors don't work with mac, or with linux, or with anything. I'm super stuck!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The MacBook Pro's HDMI port has a DVI-D implementation. This means it has no analog signal, which is what VGA relies on to connect. More information here: [apple support forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3682821?start=0&tstart=0) . Apple supplies an HDMI to DVI adapter, which could solve your problem if your monitor has a DVI port. If not, then I would suggest getting a Thunderbolt (Mini DisplayPort) to VGA cable, then using the Thunderbolt port on your Mac to link to your monitor instead.

Comment: Dangit. I was preferring to use an HDMI adapter, such that it could work with other folks' machines (not just MacBooks). I actually bought both from the store. Yes, the mini-displayport works like a charm.