# External Monitor not working on MacBook Pro 2015 with HDMI-VGA converter

Tags: hdmi, vga-adapter, vga

I have an HDMI to VGA connector and a Samsung LED screen. The screen is fine, the VGA cable is fine, the connector is fine (tried with different laptops running Ubuntu and Windows).

**The Problem**: 
I'm plugging the HDMI-VGA connector in my Macbook Pro 2015 but the display doesn't show on the external screen.

What I've tried:
I went in Displays and tried all given options like extend screen and more. The window also shows the name of the screen "SMB2230" on my Macbook and when I plug-in the HDMI, the screen flickers for a second and dock (on the right) disappears from the built-in display and I can move my mouse to the right and it also disappears but the external monitor shows the message "Check signal cable". I have tried restarting it as well but no luck.

**Note**: The screen is working with other laptops running Windows and Ubuntu with the same connector and the same VGA cable.

*Please don't tell me that I have to use MiniDisplay port/wire from Apple.*

here is an image
[image]

Comment: Have you tried restarting the machine?

Comment: @ComputerScienceStudent yes but no luck, forgot to mention it in the question.

Comment: Please check here:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/220752/macbook-pro-screen-flickering-when-using-hdmi-to-vga-adapter-to-connect-to-exter

Answer (score 1):

Try a PRAM and SMC reset. Usually helps.

Also try replugging in the connectors on both ends

Comment: Thanks for the answer, tried it but still no luck.

Comment: Could be a driver problem

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to get this to work was to put a powered HDMI splitter in between the MacBook and HDMI to VGA adapter.
MacBook > HDMI cable > powered splitter > HDMI to VGA adapter > VGA cable > monitor.

SUcks, but it works.

Answer (score -1):

Look at my answer on this forum, hope it will work for you! https://discussions.apple.com/message/30126959#30126959